# Translation morphism is not a homomorphism? Why does the inverse appear?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, algebraic-groups

Let $G$, an algebraic group, act morphically on the affine variety $X$.

Then we can also have $G$ act on the affine algebra $K[X]$ as follows:
$$\tau_x(f(y))=f(x^{-1}\cdot y),\qquad (x\in G, y\in X)$$

Then $\tau:G\to GL(K[X]),\quad \tau:x\mapsto \tau_x$.

Humphreys says that the reason that the inverse appears, is so that $\tau$ is a group homomorphism. But to me it seems that without the inverse it would be a group homomorphism, and with it, it isn't even a group homomorphism.

$\tau_{xy}(f(z))=f((xy)^{-1}\cdot z)=f(y^{-1}\cdot x^{-1}\cdot z)$ and $\tau_x\tau_yf(z)=\tau_xf(y^{-1}\cdot z)=f(x^{-1}\cdot y^{-1}\cdot z),$
so these seem to fail to be a homomorphism, where it is clear to see that without the inverse, it would be a group homomorphism.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to see this. For $x\in G$, let $m_x:X\rightarrow X$ be the map $y\mapsto x.y$. This is obviously an homomorphism : $m_{xy}=m_x\circ m_y$. Now, by definition the action on $K[X]$ is the following : $x.f:=f\circ m_{x^{-1}}$. Let us check that this is indeed an action :
$$ (xy).f=f\circ {m_{(xy)^{-1}}}=f\circ m_{y^{-1}x^{-1}}=f\circ m_{y^{-1}}\circ m_{x^{-1}}=x.(f\circ m_{y^{-1}})=x.(y.f)  $$

If you do the same reasoning with the action $x.f:=f\circ m_x$, you will see it fails to be a left action (it is in fact a right action).

Using a bit of the language of category theory, you have a left action of $G$ on $X$. Now if you consider $k[X]=\operatorname{Hom}_k(X,\mathbb{A}^1_k)$, then $G$ still acts on $k[X]$, but because it is contravariant in $X$ here, everything is turned around. So you get a right action on $k[X]$. Now this is the standard trick : using inverses, you can change every right action into a left action.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is very clear!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's perfectly correct. This is indeed a homorphism with the inverse:

Set $g=\tau_yf$. Then $\tau_x(g(z))=g(x^{-1}\cdot z)=f(y^{-1}\cdot ( x^{-1} \cdot z))$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct: $\tau_{xy}(f(z)) = f((xy)^{-1}z) = f(y^{-1}(x^{-1}z)) = \tau_y(f(x^{-1}z) = \tau_xg(z)$ if $g=\tau_yf$.

Comment: Why does taking the inverse away not yield a homomorphism?

Comment: Its simply not working when you consider a group acting on a set of functions.